# post request with nested json

Tags: php, python, json, python-requests

*php curl to python request*

Trying to make post requests to an API for ordering products. It seems that i can't figure out how to actually send a json-payload with the post-request in a way that the API receives it correctly.

The service only provides a php-example:

php-example:

```
$params = array();
$params['access_token']             = '123abc';
$params['product_total']            = 2; 
$params['product_list'] = array(
    array(
        'product_id' => 111
    ),
    array(
        'product_id' => 222
    ),
);
```

And this is my python code so far:

```
import requests

payload = {
            "access_token": "123abc",
            "product_total": 2,
            "product_list":[
                {
                    "product_id": 111,
                    ...
                },
                {
                    "product_id": 222,
                    ...
                }]
           }

r = requests.post(url, data=payload, verify=False)
r.text
> u'{"code":123,"msg":"product_id is empty"}'
```

So something is wrong with the way i send `product_list`.

I also tried:

```
import json
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), verify=False)
> u'{"code":456,"msg":"access_token is empty"}'

r = requests.post(url, json=json.dumps(payload), verify=False)
> u'{"code":456,"msg":"access_token is empty"}'
```

But than it can't read the `access_token` anymore.

I'm using `python 2.7.9` and `requests 2.18.4`.

**Update:**
Also failing...

```
r = requests.post(url, json=payloal, verify=False)
> u'{"code":456,"msg":"access_token is empty"}'
```

**Update 2:**

I looked deeper in the php-example i have from the API documentation and i found this:

```
curl_setopt($this->__ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl );
curl_setopt($this->__ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($this->__ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($this->__ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($this->__ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($this->__ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($this->__ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 ); 
curl_setopt($this->__ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($this->__params));
```

Maybe someone can spot something in this lines that I'm missing.

***Update 3:***

I can run the php-example without issues and create a order that way. But still can't do it with python.

Comment: have you tried using the `json` parameter instead of `data`? like `requests.post(url, json=payload, verify=False)`

Comment: @masterfloda, tried your suggestion - still failing

Comment: What about putting the product_id values in a list? From the requests website:
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': ['value2', 'value3']}

Comment: Each item in `product_list` consists of several items - not only `product_`. Sry i wasn't clear in my example (updated it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
payload = {
            "access_token": "123abc",
            "product_total": 2,
            "product_list[0][product_id]": 111,
            "product_list[1][product_id]": 222,
           }

r = requests.post(url, data=payload, verify=False)
```

**How i solved it:**

I reengineered the final post request that the python function should have by opening a local port and sending the working php-request to this port in order to see its payload.

```
(mac terminal)
user$ nc -l localhost 11111 # to open port
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:11111
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 115
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

access_token=123abc&product_total=2&product_list%5B0%5D%5Bproduct_id%5D=111&product_list%5B1%5D%5Bproduct_id%5D=22
```

Just have to decode the payload:

```
from urllib import parse
parse.unquote("access_token=123abc&product_total=2&product_list%5B0%5D%5Bproduct_id%5D=111&product_list%5B1%5D%5Bproduct_id%5D=22")
'access_token=123abc&product_total=2&product_list[0][product_id]=111&product_list[1][product_id]=22'
```

Now the structure of the payload is clearly visible and just have to replicate it for the python post request.

And that is how the payload looked for my initial python post request:

```
'access_token=123abc&product_total=2&product_list=product_id&product_list=product_id'
```

You can clearly see why it didn't work...

**If someone has an explanation** why the post request with a json-payload doesn't work - i am still very interested in that. Only idea i could come up with so far is that the API simply doesn't support a json-payload?

Answer (score 1):

From the experience of previous similar questions, you should try to convert your JSON (well, actually, your Python list of dicts) in `product_list` to a string representation of that same JSON before posting:

```
import requests
import json

payload = {
            "access_token": "123abc",
            "product_total": 2,
            "product_list": json.dumps([
                {
                    "product_id": 111,
                    ...
                },
                {
                    "product_id": 222,
                    ...
                }])
           }

r = requests.post(url, data=payload, verify=False)
r.text
```

Comment: still the same response: `> u'{"code":123,"msg":"product_id is empty"}'`

Comment: do you have a HTTP trace of a working request to see what is expected ? Or the documentation of the API ?

Comment: I am the only one who get timeouts on the banggood API links ?